# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. -- Error

Tags: docker, ubuntu

```
zouz@zouz:~$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d28e

zouz@zouz:~$ sudo docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

and everytime i run docker i get this error.
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

help is appreciated.

Comment: update: solved the problem by removing docker and installing Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the connectivity problem with the .sock by touching some configuration files

In **/etc/init/docker.conf** file changed the variable **"DOCKER_SOCKET"** to the path where my sock is running

```
DOCKER_SOCKET=/home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
```

then in the **/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket** file in the variable
We also change the value of **ListenStream** to the same path of the sock that we have put in the previous file

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API

[Socket]
ListenStream=/home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

when we have the two files changed and saved we can restart the services.

```
systemctl stop docker.service
systemctl stop docker.service

systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl start docker.service
systemctl start docker.service
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are facing following error when running docker -

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'
```

or

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Run following commands

```
$ sudo systemctl status docker

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

The reason is that you are trying to use systemd command to manage services on Linux but your system doesn't use systemd and (most likely) using the classic SysV init (sysvinit) system.
run following command to confirm if its above case

```
$ ps -p 1 -o comm=
init
```

so now you check again the status using

```
$ sudo service docker status
 * Docker is not running
```

you can start docker using the following command

```
sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker
```

for more detail pls refer following link
https://linuxhandbook.com/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd/

| Systemd command | Sysvinit command |
| --- | --- |
| systemctl start service_name | service service_name start |
| systemctl stop service_name | service service_name stop |
| systemctl restart service_name | service service_name restart |
| systemctl status service_name | service service_name status |
| systemctl enable service_name | chkconfig service_name on |
| systemctl disable service_name | chkconfig service_name off |